# convert python ast to json and back

Tags: python, json

I know how to convert a python `ast` to `json` by means of the `ast2json` library

```
import ast
from ast2json import ast2json
node = ast.parse("2+3", mode='eval')
e = eval(compile(node,'<string>','eval')) # equals 
node_j = ast2json(node)
```

which gives me the object

```
{'_type': 'Expression',
'body': {'_type': 'BinOp',
'col_offset': 0,
'left': {'_type': 'Num', 'col_offset': 0, 'lineno': 1, 'n': 2},
'lineno': 1,
'op': {'_type': 'Add'},
'right': {'_type': 'Num', 'col_offset': 2, 'lineno': 1, 'n': 3}}}
```

but how can I convert the `node_j` object back into an `ast` object?

Comment: ["What is the XY problem?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an opposite direction conversion tool, json2ast
https://pypi.org/project/json2ast/

*"This package is meant to work in the opposite direction of the ast2json package which takes a Python AST object as input and produces a JSON structure as output. The one function, json2ast expects a Python dictionary created by ast2json and returns a replication of the AST objects used to create that dictionary."*

https://pypi.org/project/ast2json/

Comment: yep, only nine years later, but better later than never! :) 

The `json2ast` library seems to be two years old, so it did not exist at the time of my question. Thanks for bringing this to my attention!